# Which IP is SPF checks checked against

Tags: exchange, spf

I am trying to work out which IP to put into an SPF record. I understand that SPF will extract the domain from return-path, So i guess SPF check will then do a DNS lookup to find the SPF record for domain example.com and look for approved senders. 
There might be a IP of 5.148.79.5 in there.

How do someone know thats the IP? In my situation i have

Database server: 10.90.2.117
Exchange relay server: 10.90.2.59
Main firewall (natted IP for exchange) 5.148.79.5

Why do we add in 5.148.79.5 and not 10.90.2.117 or 10.90.2.59?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because addresses on private networks are pointless for identifying the origin of a mail. The public address of your MTA is the first one a recipient can check for validity.

Comment: So a slight different scenario. Our email when relayed through on-premise Exchange actually goes like this: Server > Exchange > Firewall > Office 365 > Mimecast
Firewall, Office 365 and Mimecast all has public IPs. Which one would i need to approve in my SPF record?

Comment: In a hybrid environment you will want to add at least your own MTA's external IP *and* the PTR record provided by Microsoft for SPF lookups for O365 and/or EOP, according to their documentation. I guess your best bet is to actually send some test emails and read the headers to see what they say about originating servers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. that will give me some info to work with. i assume PTR is reverse DNS lookups?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your mails sent out via Mimecast, then add **include:_netblocks.mimecast.com** in your existing SPF or, if you do not have SPF yet, create new one for root domain ->
**v=spf1 include:_netblocks.mimecast.com ~all**

Here is the relevant link to Mimecast knowledge base ->
https://community.mimecast.com/docs/DOC-2010

I would however recommend you also to add DMARC DNS record with no policy yet (v=DMARC1; p=none) and deploy one of DMARC analyzing tool, e.g. [EasyDMARC](https://easydmarc.com/tools)

Once deployed, after 1-2 days you will start to receive DMARC aggregare reports from which you will know all sending IPs / domains used to send emails on your domain behalf, so that you can identify all your legitimate sending sources and add them to you SPF record.

[image]

Comment: Hi Zonder, this is brilliant, had a morning full of SPF, DKIM and DMARC, i am fairly confident that i cannot do much more :) Do you happen to know how to fix Body Hash Did Not Verify on DKIM signature

Comment: @RippieUK, I guess you see "Body Hash Did Not Verify" when check header of some received email ? Could you provide with full header of that email ?